# ODE Maximal solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a complete beginer in ODE. I don't understand this  theorem (i translate it): "All solution $y$ is extendable in a maximal solution $\tilde{y}$, (not necessarly unique)".
What does it mean ? I am under the impression that the theorem is trivial meanwhile the proof is based on Zorn Lemma. So i suppose i miss it and don't understand what does mean the theorem.

It is an existence theorem, so i believed that the theorem say: if $(y,I)$ is a solution then it exists an other solution  $\tilde{y}$ such that the restriction  $\tilde{y}_I=y$. This is trivial because $y$ satisfy this assertion. Moreover the solution $\tilde{y}$ is maximal in trhe sense it cannot be extended. But this thing seems trivial too, how can it be possible that it doesn' exist a maximal solution ? Sorry for the confusion i am really lost

[image]

Comment: It indeed somewhat trivial, which is why the proofs of this theorem are never all that complicated, conceptually. Formally they may require a bit of set-theoretic machinery, but that's to be expected when you're working with infinite sets of functions like this. These proofs by Zorn's Lemma or what have you are just giving names to your intuitions about why this is "obviously" true. Similarly, it seems "trivial" that from an infinite collection of sets you can construct a set which chooses one element from each set, but the formal details can lead you down a very deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively it may seem trivial, but from a theoretical point of view the Peano and Picard-Lindelöf theorems only provide local solutions to initial value problems. What happens with the solution function in the limits to the endpoints of the domain of those local solutions, if there is a limit point etc. and if there can be larger domains than those constructed in the proofs is not covered by those existence theorems. Thus the patching together of many local solutions to get a maximal solution.